Buying a home with a HOA
I currently retired and living in New Jersey. I am planning on moving to Florida into a 55 and over community. However, I am concerned about the HOA having excess rules and having their fees go way up. One of the communities I am looking at is still being built. That is the developer is still building new homes. The developer will be done building homes in about 3 years and then plans to leave. I am thinking the fact the developer will not be running the HOA is a plus. Is it?

I can't see any recent a developer would want to stay involved with the HOA after they have sold all the properties. There is no benefit to them in doing so, and there is a cost.

@keshlam - Florida has specific laws regarding when a developer MUST turn the control of the HOA to residents

Regarding 'excess' rules, read the HOA documents before buying. If some homes are occupied, speak to the residents. A developer not running an HOA is a BIG plus. While in control, they can make unilateral decisions, some of which are not in the best interest of the homeowners.

How radical do you want to be?  Generally, active senior communities are pretty intensely conformist, because seniors want a peaceful retirement, not somebody building an 80' steel boat in their backyard or running a brewery in their garage.

@BobBaerker and make sure that the HOA leadership can't just create new rules out of thin air and demand everyone follow them, which happens all too often.

Don't buy HOA-encumbered property.

Avoid HOAs. Abusive HOA boards members, and their for-profit management companies, know exactly how to work the system. The can give special favors to slightly over 50% of the homeowners & be punitive towards others. Thus, they remain in power & maintain abusive control over their little fiefdoms. It's an ugly & painful situation for many. The only recourse is protracted legal battles. Homeowners who fight must pay their own legal fees, plus their share of the legal fees to protect the board. I've heard more painful horror stories about HOAs than any other poorly regulated legal construct.

@jwenting - That's a nice sound bite but that's not how this works. HOA members are elected by residents to run the community.  They amend existing rules and regulations as well as 'legally' create new ones.  Everyone must follow them. The only alternative is to elect new ones.

@BobBaerker nice in theory, but in practice it doesn't often work like that. Take my parents' old summer home, in a HOA community. The board was made up of the few permanent residents there, and they set every meeting and election deliberately for times when as few as possible other residents were there. Result? They could do whatever they liked as they were the only ones actually voting on anything.

@jwenting - Apart from your nonsensical implication that because your parents' HOA wasn't to their liking then all HOAs are bad, your understanding of how HOAs operate is lacking. The board of directors is elected to run the association and safeguard the community.  They vote on proposals NOT the residents, whether they be permanent or part time. To repeat, residents who are not board members do not vote.

When the builder is still building residences they want to control the board. They need to keep the community looking the way that will help sell the rest of the houses.  They also want to keep the dues low.
Once the builder no longer controls the board, the owners on the HOA board can decide what to do regarding amenities, landscaping, colors and the like. Though the governing documents will also have guidelines that have to be followed.
In general once the project is done, the builder wants to sever all connections with the community, because there is no benefit to them remaining on the board.
Unless you have expertise in understanding budgets for retirement communities it is hard to predict what will happen over the decades regarding dues and the like. They need to operate the community and all the features of the community. They have to maintain those features, and save for their eventual expenses. Everything needs to be insured, which is a big issue in Florida.
In my experience, the first big jump in dues happens when they realize the community wasn't putting aside enough money in a reserve fund to replace the pool house roof, the HVAC, and the paving projects that will be needed in 10 to 20 years.

Hmmm; if the dues rate wasn't set right to begin with could the builder be sued for false advertising?

@Joshua - Builders don't operate in a vacuum.  There are state laws that the builder must adhere to.  Operational expenses are known. Financial statements must be prepared and annual tax returns must be filed.

Long before turning over a new community to an HOA, the builder sets up a transition committee of residents that it works with. The HOA’s bylaws and state laws state when an HOA can or will be turned over to owners. In Florida (where the OP asked about), it is required that 3 months after 90% of parcels in all phases have been sold, the community will start to be operated by the members.  HOA members aren't alone in this. When in doubt, they have a community attorney as well as a management company to turn to for guidance.

@BobBaerker: The people who bought early bought based on the initial dues rate set by the builder that should have been enough to cover the maintenance the first time around.

@Joshua - I don't know what your latest point is.  It's kind of hard for a builder to set rates too low in the early stages of building a community because most of a community's fully occupied expenses are either non-existent or minimally utilized (water, electricity, irrigation system, sewerage, janitorial, landscaping, pest control, office expenses, management fees, repairs, etc.).  For the most part, early on the only major expense is insurance. Therefore, it's kind of hard to falsely advertise too low of a monthly/quarterly HOA maintenance assessment.

@BobBaerker: The water and sewer mains need to be rebuilt every so often; the initial rate needs to be set so that at designed occupancy the collected feeds build up a pool to perform the needed repairs at the appointed times. This is computable function at startup time (c.f. reserve study) and the only one with enough information to do it is the builder; thus the builder must set the initial value.

@Joshua - Computable function? LOL. "The water and sewer mains need to be rebuilt every so often"??? The lifespan of water and sewerage mains is 50-100 years depending on the material used.  Not only does the initial rate have nothing to do with this but the builder is likely to be dead and gone by that time. Probably the homeowner as well.

The horror story is that when the builder has finished all of the buildings and sold all of the houses, the builder then contracts a HoA services company to run the HoA, and obtains a kickback from them for the privilege.  Is FL one of the states that has outlawed this?

TLDR:  I think you will find most HOAs, in Florida, are run well.  Those in 55+ communities even more so.
There are many laws in Florida that protect against abusive HOAs.  The best indication of how an HOA will operate is looking at neighboring HOAs.  For the most part, age 55+ communities have rules and operate in a way which would make you feel comfortable.  Why?  Because these people are of similar age to you and tend to have similar values.  Also most HOA board members have time to do the job properly.
The wife and I owned in a 55+ community which was allowed to own despite us not being of that age.  However we were not allowed to live there.  We had to have approval for our tenant, who was my wife's grandmother.  The board had some rules that young people might find restrictive and unfair.  One example is they limited the number of pets and their size one could own.   Only small dogs were allowed, no 100lb dogs which could potentially kill and old person by merely knocking them down.  The board did a great job of keeping costs low as most were also on a fixed income.
We bought during a bad economy.  The previous owners did not pay their HOA dues for quite some time.  Part of the closing was us being clear on what was owed and how much the seller and the buyer were responsible for.  At closing the HOA received all their monies plus interest and fees.  This avoided an undue responsibility on those that paid on time.
The HOA board had a retired CPA as one of the officers.  He was amazing.  You could be a part of the board.
Now if you are buying in a high rise building by the beach, you have to be prepared to open your wallet.  First salt kills most mechanical equipment, so cars and air conditions will need to be replaced more frequently than being even 5 miles inland.   (Those are personal expenses).
The stucco on the building, and sometimes even the balconies will need to be replaced or repaired.  It is not uncommon for such tenants to received a 5 figure special assessment on top of HOA dues.  To be clear, this is not the HOA being irresponsible, but part of the cost of living near the ocean/salt water.

Excellent summary of Florida HOAs.  FWIW, Florida law requires that the minimum for adult communities of 55 or older is that at least 80%” of the occupied units be of persons 55 years or older (80/20 rule). There is no requirement that the remaining 20% be people under the age of 55.  IOW, communities may decline to permit anyone under 55.

This guy covers typical Florida concrete and structural steel damage extremely well.  This is the kind of stuff you're in for.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgzjSsg4_1o He gets a little nutty after the Champlain Towers collapse, which he covers quite intensely, but then, that collapse is a "poster child".

I think the main thing my mother complained about regarding her retirement communities (one in FL, the other in NY) was the policy that residents must join the golf club, even if they were no longer physically able to golf.

How can you presume to know that someone will have "similar values" to the OP just because they're in the same age bracket??

It's understandable that one would not be happy about paying golf membership dues if no longer physically able to golf. However, the requirement to join the golf club at a retirement community is known at the time of purchase because it's in the documents.  If this occurred at a later date because a majority of residents voted to change the docs then one would have to move if one felt that the hefty gold membership dues were too much of a burden.

There are a lot of HOA horror stories you can read in various online communities  or media reports. But those might give you a skewed view of how living in a HOA-managed community feels for the majority of people. Those who have no issues with how their HOA manages their community don't have reason to go public and talk about it.
Remember:

The HOA board members are elected by the community and can be replaced by the community.
The HOA board members only have the powers the community voted to give them.
Democratic decisions made by the community are binding for the HOA board.

So if you are really dealing with an abusive HOA board, who power-trip by inventing silly rules, mishandle funds and make life miserable for home owners they don't like, then you can always run a campaign among the other members of the community to replace them. Or even campaign to vote to disband the HOA altogether and hand their responsibilities back to the municipal government.
It only gets problematic when many of the other members of the community actually agree with how the HOA runs things and you and other disgruntled members are in the minority.

or when people in the past gave the HOA very broad powers to make their own rules without any consent from the tenants. Or when the HOA are a bunch of Karens who harass people for the heck of it, rules or no rules.

@jwenting In the first case, you can make a motion on the next HOA meeting to limit their powers. In the second case, you run against them in the next HOA election. A HOA board can only abuse their power if the majority of the community lets them.

@jwenting - You appear to believe that residents must give their consent to rules made by the board of directors of an HOA. That is not the case. HOAs are private governments and HOA rules and regulations are legally binding for residents.  Also, tenants have no say in anything in an HOA.  Homeowners do.
